# Moving from CRA to Gatsby broke JSS plugins

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby, jss

In `create-react-app` I was using `react-jss` because for the `jss-plugin-expand` plugin is not included by default.
I had `<StylesProvider jss={reactJss}>` and all worked fine. However, now I switched to Gatsby and the exact same setup stopped working.
`flex: [1, 1, '70px']` is now compiled to `flex: 1, 1, 70px` (with commas).

```js
import React from 'react'
import { jss } from 'react-jss'
import { StylesProvider, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline'

export default function PagesLayout({children}){
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  )
}
```

The only difference I can think of, is that now this file is a wrapper,  and has `{children}` instead of `<App/>`

versions:

```
"react-jss": "^10.3.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

You know in Gatsby, harder to use react-jss(jss) than base react project.
I have being facing issue above like you, and you can fix it by use more Gatsby plugin with a few config

Detail in here:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-jss-provider/